# Problem with getJSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I have some problem with $.getJSON response in Chrome

The query is

```
$.getJSON("http://www.askgeo.com/api/428014/sf2t36ujv1tsf325t5734gstr4/timezone.json?callback=?&points=55.77184,37.623553",
    function(json){
        <some code>
    }
);
```

if you click on this link you'll get an json text.

By when I run this query Chrome shows an error:

*Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json*

*SyntaxError: Unexpected token :                                          timezone.json:1*

Does it try to convert json response to JavaScript object? If it is so why it cann't do that? Is there any way of resolving this problem?

in Chrome debugger I found the file "timezone.json" with this content:

```
{"code":0,"message":"ok","data":[{"timeZone":"Europe/Moscow","currentOffsetMs":14400000,"latitude":55.77184,"longitude":37.623553}]}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you've wrapped the URL in brackets and added `[1]` at the end?

Comment: I haven't seen the brackets used in a `getJSON` call like this before; what's that do?

Comment: what are the square brackets around the url for?

Comment: @leo dave and galchen: i believe that is markdown syntax within a code block

Comment: @Tentonaxe, Oh, I get it now. That's funny.

Comment: brackets and [1] were automaticly added when I insert hyperlink to the post. I edited the post. No query is correct and looks like this $.getJSON("http://www.askgeo.com/api/428014/sf2t36ujv1tsf325t5734gstr4/timezone.json?callback=?&points=55.77184,37.623553",
    function(json){
        <some code>
    }
);

Answer (score 3):

The server you are requesting data from is not setup to return JSONP. therefore, you need to build some kind of proxy to get the data for you, or use YQL.

Edit:

If you were to use YQL, this is the url you would use:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20json%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.askgeo.com%2Fapi%2F428014%2Fsf2t36ujv1tsf325t5734gstr4%2Ftimezone.json%3Fpoints%3D55.77184%2C37.623553%22&format=json&diagnostics=true
```

and for information on how I generated that url, visit:

[http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20json%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A//www.askgeo.com/api/428014/sf2t36ujv1tsf325t5734gstr4/timezone.json%3Fpoints%3D55.77184%2C37.623553%22](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20json%20WHERE%20url=%22http://www.askgeo.com/api/428014/sf2t36ujv1tsf325t5734gstr4/timezone.json?points=55.77184,37.623553%22)

You can find the url at the bottom.

Fiddle using YQL: http://jsfiddle.net/JGwU3/1/

there is however one quirk with using YQL. if the result only contains one result, it's contents is an object, however, if it is multiple, its contents will be an array. you can see the difference by console.logging the response.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

OK, my post was wrong, it is a JSONP issue. See this jQuery documentation page on how to retrieve the data from the URL:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The brackets are from the markdown editor used on stackoverflow. should be a typo

Comment: Mmm, I don't think so--I think it's a JSONP issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) it says, that you should provide the query paramaters in a separate JSON object as the second argument.

```
$.getJSON('http://www.askgeo.com/api/428014/sf2t36ujv1tsf325t5734gstr4/timezone.json', {'callback':'', 'points': '55.77184,37.623553'}, function(json) {
  alert(json.data[0].timeZone);
});
```

Works fine when I tested it.

(This is totally ignoring JSONP)

Comment: doesn't that get caught by the same-origin issue?

Comment: Yeah, of course, have it turned off here on my dev machine and didn't think about it. Sorry for mixing it up, didn't realize the ?callback was there since after I wrote the post